# I want create icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, icons

what is this error ?

I was trying to use a package to change my app icon in flutter and when I put this flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main in terminal this error appeared.

PS D:\flutter_projects\wael_cors> flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
flutter : The term 'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: dont know bt you can try remove command and then `flutter clean` and check the state, then again run the add icon command

Answer (score 0):

Flutter needs to be in your path so it can be accessed by typing 'flutter' in your terminal

The Flutter windows install docs are very good at explaining how to do this!
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path